# How does something appear as not Owned when I explicitly set it to Owned in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a Class called JobSeeker that is associated with Credit Cards.  Here is the class:

```
        public class JobSeeker : Entity, IAggregateRoot
        {
             private readonly List<CreditCard> _creditCards;
             public IEnumerable<CreditCard> CreditCards => _creditCards.AsReadOnly();
         }
```

In DBContext I have:

```
public class JobSeekerContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private static readonly Type[] EnumerationTypes = { typeof(CreditCardType) };

    public const string DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "jobseeker";

    public DbSet<JobSeeker> JobSeekers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CreditCardType> CreditCardTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Build the model
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClientRequestEntityTypeConfiguration());

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobSeeker>().OwnsMany(a => a.CreditCards);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CreditCard>().HasOne(o => o.CardType).WithMany().HasForeignKey("_creditCardTypeID");}
```

When I try top add a migration on this I get the following error:
"System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'CreditCard' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity& type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 shouldBeOwned) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 shouldBeOwned)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.EntityTEntity
at JobAssist.Services.JobSeekerMgmt.Infrastructure.JobSeekerContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\Users\m_len\source\repos\JobAssist\src\Services\JobSeekerMgmt\JobSeekerMgmt.Infrastructure\JobSeekerContext.cs:line 127
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The type 'CreditCard' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists."

I dont see how the Credit Cards is being configured as non-owned.  I am using Entity Framework Core 5. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use the same type as both a stand alone table and an owned type. EF Core automatically configures all `DbSet` properties as a stand alone table, which you don't want, so remove them. And you don't want to call `.Entity<CreditCard>(`... use `.OwnsMany(` to configure that entity.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman  If I dont call the .Entity<CreditCard> line then how will I configure the CreditCard to CreditCardType association?

Comment: Use the builder returned when you define the owned type relationship; `var ownedBuilder = ....OwnsMany(...);`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I am doing tthis in the DBContext.OnModelCreating() and using the modelBuilder passed in.:    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Build the model
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClientRequestEntityTypeConfiguration());

            modelBuilder.Entity<JobSeeker>().OwnsMany(a => a.CreditCards);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CreditCard>().HasOne(o => o.CardType).WithMany().HasForeignKey("_creditCardTypeID");
}